# The definition of $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n$ for a sequence of sets $\{A_n\}$

Tags: real-analysis

In measure theory, we call an algebrac $\mathbb{A}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra if for any sequence of sets $A_n$ in $\mathbb{A}$, $\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n\in\mathbb{A}$.
I am curious how to define $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n$.

In calculus, we define the limit of $A_n$ by language of $\epsilon$-$\delta$.

Comment: Consider $\cup(\frac{1}{n},1]$ - for a finite case (just an algebra) this results in $(\frac{1}{n},1]$ for some $n$, but for a $\sigma$-algebra we require $[0,1]\in\mathcal{A}$. See http://www.maths.kisogo.com/index.php?title=Sigma-algebra and and http://www.maths.kisogo.com/index.php?title=Types_of_set_algebras for the different set algebras and how they interact. Additionally union is defined for arbitrary "indexing sets". So for some ARBITRARY class even $I$ $x\in\bigcup_{\alpha\in I}A_\alpha\iff\exists \beta\in I[x\in A_\beta]$

Answer (score 4):

This has nothing to do with limits or $\varepsilon$-$\delta$.

If $\mathcal A$ is a collection of sets, in this case $\mathcal A=\{A_n\mid n\in\Bbb N\}$, we define $\bigcup\mathcal A=\bigcup_{A\in\mathcal A}A$ as the set $\{a\mid\exists A\in\mathcal A:a\in A\}$. This is the set of elements which appear in at least one member of the family $\mathcal A$.

So in the case of $\mathcal A=\{A_n\mid n\in\Bbb N\}$ we define $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n=\{a\mid\exists n\in\Bbb N:a\in A_n\}$.

Comment: We also write $\cup B=\{x :\exists b\in B (x\in B)\}$.

Comment: @user254665 You probably mean $\{x:\exists b\in B,x\in b\}$, and the notation is already mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

$\cup_{i=1}^\infty A_i$ is exactly all the elements that are in at least one set $A_i$.

Answer (score 2):

A set is defined by the elements it contains.  The set $$\cup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$$ contains exactly those elements that are in at least one $A_n$, for $n\in\mathbb{N}$.